# Android Kotlin: Illegal State Exception when checking if MediaPlayer is playing

Tags: android, kotlin

I am designing a simple Android application that shows a list of the user's system ringtones. When a user selects a ringtone, that ringtone is played for 5 seconds to give the user a sample of the alarm's sound. However, on the **second time** that the user selects a ringtone, the entire application crashes, yielding the following error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.alarmsampletest, PID: 24509
> java.lang.IllegalStateException
> at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
> at com.example.alarmsampletest.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onItemSelected(MainActivity.kt:60)

This seems strange, considering that I check to see that the `MediaPlayer` is not `null` before I check that the `MediaPlayer` is playing the alarm. Furthermore, what is even more strange is that this crash always occurs at the **second time** in which the user selects the alarm.

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/alarmSpinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></Spinner>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null

    private var initializingSpinner: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Retrieve a mapping of alarm names to their respective sound locations
        var alarmMapping: MutableMap<String, String> = getRingtoneList()

        // Retrieve a list of alarm names
        var alarmNames = alarmMapping.keys.toMutableList()

        // Add the alarm ringtone list to the alarm spinner
        var alarmSpinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.alarmSpinner)

        val arrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String>? =
            this?.let { ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, alarmNames) }

        arrayAdapter!!.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        alarmSpinner.adapter = arrayAdapter

        alarmSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>,
                view: View,
                position: Int,
                id: Long
            ) {
                if (initializingSpinner) {
                    // Retrieve the name of the alarm the user selected
                    val alarmName: String = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()

                    // Retrieve the file path of the selected alarm sound
                    val alarmPath: String? = alarmMapping[alarmName]

                    // Play the alarm sound
                    var alarmUri: Uri? = Uri.parse(alarmPath)

                    // Have the MediaPlayer launch our alarm sound to give users a sample :D
                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                        if (mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying) {
                            mediaPlayer?.stop()
                            mediaPlayer?.release()
                        }
                    }

                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(
                        applicationContext,
                        alarmUri
                    )


                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                        mediaPlayer?.start()

                        // Ensures that the audio sample is played for 5 seconds.
                        val timer: CountDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(5000, 5000) {
                            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                                // Nothing to do
                            }

                            override fun onFinish() {
                                if (mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying) {
                                    mediaPlayer!!.stop()
                                    mediaPlayer!!.release()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        timer.start()
                    }
                }

                initializingSpinner = true;
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
        }
    }

    // Function which retrieves a complete mapping of the uesr's ringtones:
    // alarm name (string) : sound file path
    private fun getRingtoneList(): MutableMap<String, String> {
        val manager = RingtoneManager(this)
        manager.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM)
        val cursor: Cursor = manager.cursor
        val list: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            val notificationTitle: String =
                cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX)
            val notificationUri: String = cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.URI_COLUMN_INDEX)
                .toString() + "/" + cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.ID_COLUMN_INDEX)
            list[notificationTitle] = notificationUri
        }

        return list
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception about media player states. After you release the media player, it goes into end state and in end state you should not call is playing method otherwise it throws the exception. For further info you can look at the graph at the link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#isPlaying() . To solve your problem, you can set media player reference to null after releasing it in onFinish callback of timer and in the first null check of the spinner selection callback.